# CSS bottom alignment with variable padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to use CSS to align a div at the bottom of a parent div. However, the catch is that I need that bottom aligned div to move down if another sibling div runs into it. The picture below shows some examples of the various alignments that could occur. The first two are ideal and I could easily do those using absolute and setting bottom to 0. However, that solution breaks down on the third example because the text would overlap the bottom div.

[Image showing what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgfGH.png)

Comment: add some of your `html` code or try making a jsfiddle demo and edit your question.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: you must set position of all div to relative and then set the position of the div to bottom

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all images are of the same size

HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <div>
    <div class="image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div>
      <div class="top">
        <div>
          Top
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div>
          Bottom
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .item {display: table;}
  .item > div {display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;}
  .text {width: 100%;}
  .text > div {height: 144px; width: 100%; display: table;}
  .text > div > div {display: table-row;}
  .text > div > div > div {display: table-cell;}
  .top {height: 100%;}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/2kpcda79/)